# Getting a class member by string in Java

Tags: java

I honestly am not sure I'm calling these things by their right names, so apologies.

I've got this in one class file:

```
class eSpecies {
    protected String name;
    protected String file;
    protected int hp;
    protected int atk;
    protected int exp;
    protected int type;
    public int kill;
    protected String flavour;


    eSpecies(String name, String file, int hp,int atk, int exp, int type, int kill, String flavour){
        this.name=name;
        this.file=file;
        this.hp=hp;
        this.atk=atk;
        this.exp=exp;
        this.type=type;
        this.kill=kill;
        this.flavour=flavour;

    }
}

public class enemyDB{

    static eSpecies lsp     = new eSpecies("Lesser Shelled Pincher", "lsp", 500, 30, 50, 1, 0, "this is a small bug");
    static eSpecies gsp     = new eSpecies("Greater Shelled Pincher", "gsp", 50000, 50, 500, 1, 0, "this is a small bug");

}
```

and have been referencing it in another like so:

```
eSpecies e = enemyDB.lsp;
```

I want to know if it's possible to essentially do this:

```
String type = "lsp";
eSpecies e = enemyDB.type;
```

Obviously this doesn't work, but I hope the idea is clear enough- getting a class object by using a string to get part of its name. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a Map will do what you want. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: Used a map in the end and got it to work perfectly- thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

It's called "reflection". From another post:

```
public void printFields(Object obj) throws Exception {
    Class<?> objClass = obj.getClass();

    Field[] fields = objClass.getFields();
    for(Field field : fields) {
        String name = field.getName();
        Object value = field.get(obj);

        System.out.println(name + ": " + value.toString());
    }
}
```

But you should avoid it if possible. It's not really good practice because it destroys the entire idea of strongly typed languages like Java.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, I can't gleam how to apply this to my code (I'm sure I'm just being thick)- which part is which? Also, if it's not good practice, what's an alternative?

Comment: call printFields(enemyDB) and it will print all fields of that object including values.

Answer (score 0):

Reflection can be the way to achieve this. As per documentation:

> If the underlying field is a static field, the obj argument is ignored; it may be null.

Also the field static should be visible. Like public field for example.

> **public** static eSpecies lsp = new eSpecies("Lesser Shelled Pincher",...

Need of your code is to fetch directly by name rather iterating over fields. For example:

```
String type = "lsp";
eSpecies ep1 = (eSpecies) enemyDB.class.getField(type).get(null);
```

Comment: Currently getting "Unhandled Exception: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException", despite it definitely existing. I've made the field public, not sure what else could be wrong?

Comment: Are you using some framework ? 
Have you put them inside try catch .. Try this as... 

try {
   eSpecies ep1 = (eSpecies) enemyDB.class.getField(type).get(null);
   System.out.println(ep1.name);   
  } catch (NoSuchFieldException e1) {
   e1.printStackTrace();
  } catch (SecurityException e1) {
   e1.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
   e1.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
   e1.printStackTrace();
  }

Comment: Working in Android Studio so I don't think most of that code works... I'm at a loss

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/learn-java-for-android-development-reflection-basics--mobile-3203

Comment: It doesn't work, but I'll have a look at this tutorial, thanks :)